Unexpected 16px Margin Between Header and Content in Tailwind CSS with .space-y-4
I'm using Tailwind CSS in a React project and noticed an unexpected 16px margin between my header and the content below. After inspecting the elements, I found that the margin is caused by the space-y-4 utility class applied to a div wrapping the content.
Here’s the relevant part of my code:
<div className="space-y-4 lg:basis-3/5">
  <Input />
  <PostCard />
</div>

Here is my full Component
function Profile() {
  return (
    <>
      <header className="w-full">
        <div className="bg-main-white">
          <div className="ml-auto mr-auto w-full rounded-bl-lg rounded-br-lg bg-main-white sm:w-[90%] md:w-[85%] lg:w-[80%] xl:w-[70%]">
            <ProfileCover />
            <ProfileUserAvatar />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="ml-auto mr-auto mt-4 flex w-[90%] flex-col space-y-4 md:w-[85%] lg:w-[80%] lg:flex-row lg:gap-4 xl:w-[70%]">
          <div className="space-y-4 lg:basis-2/5">
            <ProfileInfo />
            <ProfileGallery />
            <ProfileFriends />
          </div>

          <div className="space-y-4 lg:basis-3/5">
            {/* <PostInput /> */}
            <Input />
            <PostCard />
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    </>
  );
}

I understand that this rule is responsible for the vertical spacing between the child elements, but I’m not sure how to control or remove the margin between the header and the content.
I tried to remove the space-y-4 but it didn't work.
In my CSS, I see the following rule generated by Tailwind:
.space-y-4 > :not([hidden]) ~ :not([hidden]) {
    --tw-space-y-reverse: 0;
    margin-top: calc(1rem* calc(1 - var(--tw-space-y-reverse)));
    margin-bottom: calc(1rem* var(--tw-space-y-reverse));
}

When I disabled this property in the dev tool  --tw-space-y-reverse: 0; the problem got fixed but I don't know how to apply the solution to my code or what it even means.
My Questions:
How can I prevent this extra margin from affecting the space between my header and content?
Is there a better way to handle spacing between elements using Tailwind CSS without causing unintended gaps?

Removing the space-y-4 class should be sufficient in removing the 16px spacing between the Input and PostCard components:


const placeholderComponent = (name) => () => <div>{name}</div>
const ProfileCover = placeholderComponent('ProfileCover');
const ProfileUserAvatar = placeholderComponent('ProfileUserAvatar');
const ProfileInfo = placeholderComponent('ProfileInfo');
const ProfileGallery = placeholderComponent('ProfileGallery');
const ProfileFriends = placeholderComponent('ProfileFriends');
const Input = placeholderComponent('Input');
const PostCard = placeholderComponent('PostCard');

function Profile() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <header className="w-full">
        <div className="bg-main-white">
          <div className="ml-auto mr-auto w-full rounded-bl-lg rounded-br-lg bg-main-white sm:w-[90%] md:w-[85%] lg:w-[80%] xl:w-[70%]">
            <ProfileCover />
            <ProfileUserAvatar />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="ml-auto mr-auto mt-4 flex w-[90%] flex-col space-y-4 md:w-[85%] lg:w-[80%] lg:flex-row lg:gap-4 xl:w-[70%]">
          <div className="space-y-4 lg:basis-2/5">
            <ProfileInfo />
            <ProfileGallery />
            <ProfileFriends />
          </div>

          <div className="lg:basis-3/5">
            {/* <PostInput /> */}
            <Input />
            <PostCard />
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<Profile/>);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-QVs8Lo43F9lSuBykadDb0oSXDL/BbZ588urWVCRwSIoewQv/Ewg1f84mK3U790bZ0FfhFa1YSQUmIhG+pIRKeg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-6a1107rTlA4gYpgHAqbwLAtxmWipBdJFcq8y5S/aTge3Bp+VAklABm2LO+Kg51vOWR9JMZq1Ovjl5tpluNpTeQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.5"></script>

<div id="app"></div>



This supported by the fact that disabling --tw-space-y-reverse declaration removes the spacing too.
Perhaps removing the space-y-4 class did not work for you because you removed the wrong one?

Thank you I tried to remove the property from the parent div and it worked!
